Short Story. A human jewel thief teams up with a mountain sized alien thief with psychic powers who doesn't like to leave his planet
The jewel thief starts the story in jail. He is contacted telepathically by a psychic alien. He proposes they team up. The alien can use his psychic powers to make all the people nearby believe the human thief has every right to walk off with the jewels. Then they can split the loot 50-50. The alien says he needs the human 's help as he doesn't like to leave his home world.
The crime goes very smoothly. The human thief walks right by the guards and into the treasure room. The king who owns the treasure is right there in the room. The king accepts that the human is quite entitled to walk off with the jewels.
Once the human is back in his spaceship, his accomplice sends him directions of how to travel to his home planet.
He arrives and takes out the jewels so they can share them out. The alien is a giant creature, his foot much larger than the human.

 He says sorry you have to die so noone can extract my identity and location from your brain. A huge foot squishes the poor man.


This appears to be "Never Trust a Thief" by Robert Silverberg (writing as Ivar Jorgensen), originally published in Imagination Stories of Science and Fantasy in February 1958.
The jewel thief starts the story in jail. He is contacted telepathically by a psychic alien. He proposes they team up.

"That ought to hold you, Kiley!" the Alpherazian growled. "You've stolen your last jewel, Earthman."
"Get out of here!" Kiley said thinly. "Don't stand here and gloat. I'd be free and out of here if that crazy alarm hadn't popped off."
The guard chuckled. "Relax and cool off, Kiley. You've got plenty of time to get used to your new home."
The door clanged shut. Kiley spat in the darkness as he heard the bolt slipping home—the unbreakable, foolproof bolt of the escape proof Alpheraz jail. And then—
How would you like to be free in five minutes? a voice asked.
"Huh? Who's there?" Kiley looked around, narrowing his eyes to see in the foggy blackness, but there was no one within sight.
Don't strain your eyes, the voice said—and Kiley realized it was an unspoken voice in his mind. I'm a thousand light-years away. The name is Thaklaru.

The crime goes very smoothly. The human thief walks right by the guards and into the treasure room. The king who owns the treasure is right there in the room. The king accepts that the human is quite entitled to walk off with the jewels.

The big coup came when Kiley grew tired of the planet's pleasures. He travelled to the Emperor's palace.
The guards bowed to him as he approached. "Good afternoon, your majesty!"
Kiley smiled politely and kept on going. He walked quickly through the palace, stopping only to ask a butler where the jewel-room was.
As it turned out, the Emperor himself was in the jewel-room. "Pardon me, your majesty," Kiley said. "I'll have to have some of these, I'm afraid."
The monarch looked up, met Kiley's eye, and froze. "Of course," he said politely. "Go right ahead." And he stood to one side while Kiley plundered the crown jewels.

The ending also matches your spoiler, but so as not to spoil the spoiler, I won't quote it.  The link above will take you to the complete text on Project Gutenberg if you want to verify it.
